# Java get class from File or file path

Tags: java

I am trying to get a class and call a method of that class. I can get the resource, from that i have a File and from that an absolute path to my class, but i can not get the actual class out of it so that i can call the method. How could i get the class from the resource/file/path? 
Class.forName gives---> "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"

```
PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath*:com/company/worker/module/*.class");
log.info("found RES::  " + Arrays.toString(resources));
Arrays.asList(resources).forEach(r -> {
    try
    {//////////////////////////Class.forName gives---> "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException"///////
        Method handleRequest = Class.forName(r.getFile().getAbsolutePath()).getDeclaredMethod("handleRequest",
            Parameter.class, java.lang.String.class);
        handleRequest.invoke(searchParameter, myType);
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException | SecurityException | NoSuchMethodException
        | ClassNotFoundException | IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

Comment: `Class.forName` expects the fully qualified name of the class, not the file path. So you should be converting the resource name to `"com.company.worker.module.<ClassName>"` somehow.

Comment: @Slaw that does work, thank you!(answer so i can accept)

Comment: I only provided a hint. Since you figured out the full solution it would probably be best for you to answer your own question so this Q&A can potentially help someone else in the future.